# Backbone filter multiple collections on multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am hoping some can help me, I have managed to create a tool that searches/filters a collections models based on various attributes (basically all the attributes of a model).

```
filterUsers: function (collection, filterValue) {
    var filteredCollection;

    if (filterValue === "") {
        return collection.toJSON();
    }

    return filteredCollection = collection.filter(function (data) {

        return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function (value) {

            if (value != undefined) {

                value = (!isNaN(value) ? value.toString() : value);
                //var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

                return value.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;

            }

        });

    });

}
```

Now this works fine, for one collection, but is it possible to filter of multiple (2) collections? And return a merged set of results?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter two collections, you can run your filter function on both collections and then merge the results.

```
    if (filterValue === "") {
        return collection.toJSON();
    }

    var filterThroughValue = function(data) {

        return _.some(_.values(data.toJSON()), function(value) {

            if( value != undefined ) {

                value = (!isNaN(value) ? value.toString() : value);
                //var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

                return value.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;

            } 

        });

    };

    return filteredCollection = _.union(
        collection1.filter(filterThroughValue),
        collection2.filter(filterThroughValue)
    );

}
```

Basically, you're declaring your filter function(how you want your values filtered) and then passing that as the argument for your .filter function.

Checkout the `_.union` function in underscore: http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#union